# Biquad cookbook formula for broadcast FM de-emphasis?

Tags: filter-design, biquad, frequency-modulation

Can a simple IIR biquad filter be used as an audio de-emphasis filter for broadcast FM radio?  If so, how does one translate the filter requirements (50 uS time constant in the U.S.?) into parameters for one of the common (e.g. RBJ's) biquad cookbook algorithms, given typical audio sample rates?  Is the formula for a low shelving filter appropriate?

Comment: it seems to me that the de-emphasis is a 1st-order LPF with the corner frequency at $\frac{1}{2 \pi \, 75 \, \mu S}$.  all of the shelves and filters in the cookbook are 2nd order.  you can experiment and see if a shelf will match up well enough.

Comment: Both answers below seem to meet the bill? Can one be selected or were you looking for something more?

Answer (score 3):

You could also implement a 2nd order IIR filter which has response of 1st order filter by using some other TF but one used in RBJ's cookbook. 
Here's one way to do it using MZT (C++).

```
double Fs = 44100; // higher sample rate results better filter accuracy 
double T1 = 0.000075; // time constant
double p1 = -exp(-1.0/(Fs*T1));
double z1 = 1 + z1;

a0 = 1.0;
a1 = p1;
a2 = 0;

b0 = 1.0;
b1 = z1;
b2 = 0;

% swap between a1, b1 to select pre- or de-emphasis
```

Coefficients from above calculations adds +13.63dB gain so you need to normalize before use.

Same as Octave code:

```
% PACKAGES
pkg load control
pkg load signal

clear all;
clc;

fs = 44100;
samplingtime = 1/fs;

% analog prototype
A2 = [1];
B2 = [0.000075 1];
Ds = tf(B2, A2); % swap between A2 and B2 to select pre- or de-emphasis
Ds = Ds/dcgain(Ds);

% MZT
T1 = 0.000075; % 75us
z1 = -exp(-1.0/(fs*T1));
p1 = 1+z1;

a0 = 1.0;
a1 = p1;
a2 = 0;

b0 = 1.0;
b1 = z1;
b2 = 0;

% swap between a1, b1 to select pre- or de-emphasis

Bmzt = [b0 a1 b2]
Amzt = [a0 b1 a2]

DzMZT = tf(Amzt, Bmzt, samplingtime);
DzMZT = DzMZT/dcgain(DzMZT);

%% Plot
wmin = 2 * pi * 20.0; % 20Hz
wmax = 2 * pi * ((fs/2.0) - (fs/2 - 20000)); 20kHz

figure(1);
bode(Ds, 'b', DzMZT, 'c', {wmin, wmax});
legend('Analog prototype', 'MZT 2nd order','location', 'northwest');
grid on;
```

There are few other ways to calculate the coefficients as like what mentioned [here](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=471746&start=15).

If you don't want to code then here are (75us) IIR coefficients for most common Fs:

```
44100
den = [ 1 -0.2430506562509079 -0.3653116688328392 ]
num = [ 0.226236781592716 0.1524695626369773 0.01293133068655965 ]

48000
den = [ 1 -0.2625656192085276 -0.3736509425970024 ]
num = [ 0.2102915623850396 0.1415200473180778 0.01197182849135262 ]

88200
den = [ 1 -0.3702185951814965 -0.419953874650389 ]
num = [ 0.1217100727211314 0.08132561501764404 0.006791842429339071 ]

96000
den = [ 1 -0.3813262768034237 -0.424764645791489 ]
num = [ 0.1125121591800709 0.07513002079134688 0.006266897433669414 ]

176400
den = [ 1 -0.4405600251706213 -0.4505357896180226 ]
num = [ 0.06328932872397297 0.04212236025403318 0.003492496233349943 ]

192000
den = [ 1 -0.4464885169088165 -0.4531262255096845 ]
num = [ 0.05834721577148291 0.03882109525679095 0.003216946553225094 ]

352800
den = [ 1 -0.4775710488916642 -0.4667412351991018 ]
num = [ 0.03239176683609103 0.02151798489625147 0.001777964176891494 ]

384000
den = [ 1 -0.4806342452619782 -0.4680860610215655 ]
num = [ 0.02982988806358219 0.01981315821469544 0.00163664743817871 ]
```

*Magnitude error less than 0.1 dB (20Hz-20kHz)*

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [this excellent RDS tutorial](https://pysdr.org/content/rds.html), and [original source](https://github.com/joeugenio/sdr/blob/main/fm_audio.py):

De-emphasis filter, $H(s) = \frac {1} {RC.s + 1}$, implemented as IIR filter via a bilinear transform:

```
bz, az = sig.bilinear(1, [75e-6, 1], fs=sample_rate)
x = sig.lfilter(bz, az, x)
```

It works as expected on this [sample of US FM broadcast](https://github.com/777arc/498x/blob/master/fm_rds_250k_1Msamples.iq):

[image]

Comment: One thing that you should keep in mind is that the bilinear transform maps $z=-1$ (which is Nyquist) to $s=j\infty$.  So your LPF is gonna take a dive as we get up to Nyquist.  Now if your sample rate is something like 44.1 kHz, that dive at high frequencies might be something you don't want.  Then it may well be that a shelf filter with something that levels off at high frequencies might be better.  The lower corner of the shelf is the same (whatever corresponds to 75 microseconds).  But there should be a zero near $z=-1$ to level it off a little.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I added some plots, incl. the frequency response. My understanding was the whole channel was pre-emphasized (-/+ 125 kHz), not the L+R or L-R portions. Therefore, the filter b/w is -/+ 125 kHz and the very low response regions are past -/+ 100 kHz. Correct me if I'm wrong (it seems I'm).

Comment: what's your sample rate?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I've only a little experience, I've two code sections, which are different. In the [first one](https://pysdr.org/content/rds.html#wrap-up-and-final-code) the sample rate is 250k, the signal is FM-demodulated, de-emphasized, then decimated by 6 to get 41.66k. In the [second one](https://github.com/joeugenio/sdr/blob/main/fm_audio.py), samples at 250k are FM-demodulated, decimated by 6 and de-emphasized with a filter calculated for 250k. I used the first example to produce the plots.

Comment: With such a high sample rate, this frequency-warping effect of the bilinear transform can be neglected.  I forgot about this de-emphasis happening to the entire multiplex FM signal (with the L-R bumped up to 38 kHz and other subbands).   I thought it was just being done to the audio. So my 44.1 kHz sample rate was not realistic.  But you can see at ±125 kHz that your LPF filter response that was doing a nice, predictable -6 dB/octave, that it takes a dive at 125 kHz.  It's not a problem for you, but it sometime ***is*** a problem for other audio applications with slower sample rate.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Thanks for the explanation and your time. I was not able to understand the extent of the pre-emphasis, the only specs I could find ([ITU-R BS.450-3](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bs/R-REC-BS.450-3-200111-S!!PDF-E.pdf)) have an ambiguous sentence for that: "*The RF signal consists of a carrier frequency-modulated by the sound signal to be transmitted, after pre-emphasis, with a maximum frequency deviation equal to...*"

Comment: Well, that's electrical-engineering-speak.  So with Frequency Modulation, the carrier frequency is caused to deviate from its nominal value by *"±75 kHz or ±50 kHz"* (depending on which side of the old Iron Curtain you live).  That mean as the instantaneous value $x(t)$ approaches its maximum positive value, the carrier frequency deviates to +75 kHz.  As $x(t)$ goes to its maximum negative the deviation is -75 kHz.  But the bandwidth of wideband FM is even more than that.  Perhaps ±125 kHz.  Hence the sample rate of 250 kHz.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I found [a little bit more](https://www.reddit.com/r/radio/comments/tlg97h/why_were_19_and_38_khz_chosen_as_the_subcarrier/): The channel width is 200 kHz, and each audio channel are 15k. It seems each audio channels is individually pre-emphasized (so the filter width is not 200 or 150 kHz, but 15 kHz, see [page 20](https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/spectrum-management-telecommunications/sites/default/files/attachments/2022/BETS-6-i2a1-2021-06EN.pdf)). Thanks again Robert.

Comment: Actually, mins, I don't think that the de-emphasis filter is applied to each audio channel separately. It is applied the **composite** audio signal that comes out of the FM demodulator. At *baseband*, it **is** just the regular audio signal, the sum of left and right channels (L+R). Broadcast FM does frequency division multiplexing and the L-R signal is bumped up to 38 kHz (and there is a pilot sinusoid at 19 kHz to synchronize demultiplexing the L-R signal). But the pre-emphasis is applied to the whole composite signal before modulating. So also is the de-emphasis applied after demodulation.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: You're right each subcarrier (? I mean LSB+USB) separately. Now I understand a little bit better  I've reordered the process logically, and updated my plots with the result.

Comment: LSB and USB are notions that apply to single-sideband (SSB).  This is not exactly that, but everything is related. What happens in broadcast FM is that the two audio channels, L and R, are turned into two other audio signal, L+R and L-R. (You can easily see how to reacquire the separate L and R out of L+R and L-R.) Now nothing is done to L+R and a monophonic FM receiver will receive L+R as a mono signal just as FM did before stereo. The L-R signal is bumped up, using double-sideband AM modulation, to 38 kHz.  So its band is from 38-15 to 38+15 kHz. That DSB is added to baseband before FM mod.